# Creating single file installer for .NET application

Tags: c#, packaging

The installer for my .NET app consists of two file MyApp.msi and setup.exe.
I want to have a single installer MyApp.exe (self extracting archive will do) with a specified icon.
How can I do that? Is there any free tool available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[InnoSetup](http://www.innosetup.com/) and [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) are free tools for creating application setups.

For InnoSetup, [ISTool](http://www.istool.org/) makes it very easy to create setup scripts.

Comment: Do these tools create single-file installers?

Comment: Do they support MSI? Last time I checked, at least InnoSetup didn't. But the poster with the numeric name already has an MSI, so he would need InnoSetup or NSIS just for the self-extraction and calling msiexec, I guess.

Comment: @OregonGhost: I am not entirely sure about the support. However, the setup executable created with InnoSetup can execute the MSI once it has extracted the files.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Technically the MSI is a single-file installer.  It can be double-clicked to install the application.  Setup.exe just launches the MSI.

Comment: Unfortunately, double-clicking an MSI won't upgrade to a later version. It will fail instead with a message indicating that the application is already installed. That's why you typically supply an exe file.

Answer (score 2):

A couple that I've seen:

- One built into Windows: the [IExpress Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd346760.aspx).
- I've also used [ZipFusion](http://www.skaro.net/zipfusion/), which is quite good.
- [Self-Extracting installer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/sfxinst.aspx) on Code-Project.